# JRadioButton selection to String

Tags: java, string, swing, jradiobutton, getselection

I have a selection of JRadioButtons in a group. In this case they are contained in ButtonGroup "group".

An example of a button would be reviewrequest = new JRadioButton("request for review"); etc.

I am trying to convert the selected item into a string with:
categorystring = group.getSelection().toString(); (For sake of the example we will be selecting the button above)

Whenever I use this method however, instead of getting what I would like the (reviewrequest) or even ("request for review") I get something like this for a new String value:

javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel@482fdd28

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `ButtonGroup#getSelection()` is returning the ButtonModel for the JRadioButton that is now selected, and you're seeing the `public String toString()` returned from this ButtonModel object, and this information is not terribly useful.

For your code to work, you will want to set the actionCommand of the JRadioButtons by calling `.setActionCommand(...)` passing in the String of interest, and then getting this from the ButtonModel:

```
ButtonModel model = group.getSelection();

// always first check that something is indeed selected
if (model != null) {
    categorystring = model.getActionCommand();
}
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ButtonModelExample extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] BUTTON_TEXTS = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField(10);
    
    public ButtonModelExample() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Result:"));
        topPanel.add(resultField);
        resultField.setFocusable(false);
        
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (String buttonText : BUTTON_TEXTS) {
            JRadioButton radioBtn = new JRadioButton(buttonText);
            radioBtn.setActionCommand(buttonText);
            radioBtn.addChangeListener(cl -> {
                ButtonModel buttonModel = buttonGroup.getSelection();
                if (buttonModel != null) {
                    String text = buttonModel.getActionCommand();
                    resultField.setText(text);
                }
            });
            radioPanel.add(radioBtn);
            buttonGroup.add(radioBtn);
        }
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(radioPanel);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            ButtonModelExample mainPanel = new ButtonModelExample();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Took me a minute to understand but it worked! Schanks!!